# What to do with a blank layer in a multilayer PCB

Tags: high-speed, multi-layer

Currently I'm working on a PCB that doesn't really need to be 6 layers, but I had to manufacture this project with my other 6 layers. Here is a problem, I have a blank layer; no signal or anything on this plane. Should I leave it empty or make it a GND plane?

My stack is:

### Layer 1 ------ Sig / GND

### Layer 2 ------ GND Plane

### Layer 3 ------ Blank

### Layer 4 ------ PWR Plane

### Layer 5 ------ GND Plane

### Layer 6 ------ Sig / PWR

Comment: Are you doing blind or buried vias?

Comment: blind via or maybe through-hole  if i can manage to change some component

Comment: Combination of unused inner layer, blind and/or buried vias is a very strange one. Have you considered pwr-gnd-pwr-gnd-pwr-gnd?

Comment: yes theres is still blank plane i mean i can use it for routing some signals but its not really necessary i can still do routing on bot

Comment: In what way you want suggestions to use it? Fill with GND or VCC, or draw a neat picure as an easter egg?

Comment: i want to use it as pwr plane if possible i'n not sure that 2 power plane or 2 gnd that are adjacent are going to cause any emi problem

Comment: @Settasak no? you can just use it as a power plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a huge waste.

1. Make it a signal plane. I'm *sure* you will find a use for it while
   you are routing layers 1 and 6.
2. Or if you have more than one widespread voltage on your PCB make it
   a power plane for that voltage.

Comment: yep but if i want to use that for signal i need blind via its will cost more than just waste it btw adjacent pwr plane is alright?

Comment: @Settasak Why would you need blind vias to access an inner layer? You already need thru vias to go between top/bottom signal layers.

Comment: blind via to GND plane and on bottom layer is just some regulator that going into layer 4 so now i dont have any thru via

Comment: @Settasak So don't use blind vias. Thru-vias don't need to connect to every plane they put a hole through. If they did you would never be able to connect signals between your signal layers together if power/ground planes were in between.

Comment: Sound like this will be an expensive PCB without good reason.

Comment: yep trying to get more knowledge here sorry :(